# Additional hard and flash drives not detected/mounted automatically in bookmarks/computer

Tags: 12.04, unity, mount, hard-drive, automount

I restored a copy of my Ubuntu partitions that was made yesterday.  Everything is OK, except that I cannot see my additional hard drives from the launcher (they were showing when the disk image was made).  If I mount them from the terminal, then they show up in the bookmarks, but after I restart, they disappear again.

Contents of mount:

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/kaven/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=kaven)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/Storage type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/Win7 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Contents of fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=063c3b6a-cd55-4d31-bb89-1afa1e5823e8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ac9cee77-f306-4da6-b404-27f9db390e2e none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Contents of sudo blkid:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="063c3b6a-cd55-4d31-bb89-1afa1e5823e8" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="ac9cee77-f306-4da6-b404-27f9db390e2e" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Storage" UUID="6A4C3AF14C3AB7A1" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="B6E2DEADE2DE70DB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="b464937b-4d07-4c50-8c87-7fde6b3eeca5" TYPE="ext4"
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Dear Fabby, I added the information you requested :)  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi again, Fabby.  I posted the result of blkid.  Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Could you delete all of the comments as they are in your question now anyway and to keep things tidy here... (already done the same with mine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/etc/fstab` was not restored and does not contain the necessary statements to mount the partitions on your second hard drive at boot time.

To do this, add the following lines to the end of your `/etc/fstab`:

```
#mount /dev/sdb 1 and 2 at boot time:
UUID=6A4C3AF14C3AB7A1  /media/Storage  ntfs-3g  defaults,noexec,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0  2
UUID=B6E2DEADE2DE70DB  /media/Win7     ntfs-3g  defaults,noexec,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0  2
```

and both `sdb1` and `sdb2` will be mounted at boot!

As you didn't specify a mount point for `sdb3`, I can't give it for you, but you should be able to figure that out by yourself by now by looking at the rest of your `fstab` [and reading the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

### ;-)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: You're welcome.  The only 'Thank you" we require here on this site is the acceptance or upvote button!  ;-)